# Trying to log in to Keycloak Admin WS

Tags: rest, keycloak

I need to configure realms in Keycloak by the Admin WS accessible at the path

```
http://KeycloakServer:8081/auth/admin/realms
```

So in Postman I run the following request

URL: `http://KeycloakServer:8081/auth/admin/realms`

Method: `POST`

Body:

```
{
    "enabled": true,
    "id": "TestRealm",
}
```

I get a `401 Unauthorized` response, so I think it is necessary to authenticate to the Admin WS. But in the docs I cannot find any information about the type of authentication required and the syntax.
Do you know how to authenticate to the Keycloak WSs?

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do a POST request to `https://hostname:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`

Sets the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

and put the following in the body:

```
username=<username>&password=<password>&client_id=admin-cli&grant_type=password
```

Comment: In version 1.9.7 I am doing the exact same steps. I get the access_token which I then put in the header as follows Authorization: Bearer mytoken, but I still get 401 Unauthorized. Is it something I am missing?

Comment: I tried the solution it works, One possible reason why it didn't work for you is that the token expires in 60 seconds. So retry it.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick for you. Do a post on

`URI - /auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`

with Headers as below

1. `username=<admin username>`
2. `password=<admin password>`
3. `client_id=security-admin-console`
4. `grant_type=password`
5. `Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

This will return you a JSON, with `access_token` in it. Take the token and use it as the Authorization Bearer Token in your request. It should work.

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @aksappy! However, it's incorrect because since 1.7.0 security-admin-console is disable by default and those fields are not headers but are part of the request body. I made a new answer.

Comment: How do you enable security-admin-console ?