# Cannot reach Keycloak Admin REST endpoints as described by the documentation

Tags: rest, keycloak

In the [Keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.0/rest-api/index.html) the base path is defined as: `localhost:8080/auth`

But if we try to reach the documented endpoints we always get a Not Found response.

We get a 404 if we try to access the endpoint to get the top-level representation of the **master** realm: `GET /{realm}` like:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/master
```

But if we try it like:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/master
```

we receive a successful response.

Are we overlooking something or is this an error in the documentation?

Comment: Seems to be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48507224/cant-access-keycloak-rest-api-methods-404).
So it looks like an error in the documentation. Because there is no hint to the **admin/realms** part of the path.